# Separate Surname and Forename table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

My boss want me to Split Person table  into Surname and Forename table and then link to Person table with relationship.The purpose of it is basically eliminate data redundancy. Is it a Concrete suggestion?. Is it good to have separate table for forename and surname ???

Comment: No I think not to make separate table for name and surname. Why not separate into two columns.

Comment: a database can be normalized to the degree that it degrades performance. Database normalization should fit the application needs. I suggest you ask him for his reasoning on why to do this. he may have a valid reason for specific application design.

Answer (score 2):

No. That is not good RDBMS. If each person has one and only one surname and forename (as is most always the case) then those fields should be added to the existing table and the "name" field removed.

Comment: more than 1 could share a surname ;)

Comment: @SecretSquirrel Just for that I'm putting up one of those squirrel blockers on my bird feeder.

Answer (score 2):

Your boss is a muppet. Any “data redundancy” gains is quickly offset—and taken over—by a performance hit of having to join and query separate tables for a user’s name, increasing application complexity and in turn development time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends :)

If the Person table is not *really* huge then it is really an overkill.

But if this table is going to grow humongously then perhaps it makes sense to *partition* it vertically by splitting it into 2 tables.

The arguments you can give to *re-think* on this new design is that it will take more time for select queries (as there will be joins involved), it will take more time to even save data because there will be multiple tables/indexes involved, and slightly more complicated to retrieve data due to joins etc.